# Emacs rebind C-i while keeping <tab> bindings

Tags: emacs, key-binding, aquamacs

I'm using Aquamacs. It can distinguish between `<tab>`, the actual tab key, and `TAB`, which comes from typing `C-i`. I want to bind `C-i` to `'next-line` permanently. This works for that:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'next-line)
```

But then mode maps override TAB with auto-complete behavior or whatever and I lose my next-line functionality. I could put my binding in the overriding-terminal-local-map, but I'd rather the mode maps remap `<tab>` so I can still use the function that the mode assigns to tab.

I can manually rebind tab for every mode I use, but I'm hoping there's an easy way to redirect all the `TAB` mappings to the tab key without messing up `C-i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a little tricky, but possible.  What I do for this exact situation is create a minor-mode, namely `gvol-mode`, and then in it bind <kbd>C-i</kbd> to `previous-line` (or whatever you want).  Then I bind <kbd><tab></kbd> to the function below.

```lisp
(defun gvol-indent-for-tab-command ()
  "This is to fix `indent-for-tab-command' for `gvol-mode'.
It runs [tab] or C-i with `gvol-mode' nil because `gvol-mode'
binds C-i to a different command.  Ideally this should take into
account window system so that it can DTRT in a terminal (whatever
the right thing is)."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((gvol-mode nil)
         (command (or (key-binding [tab])
                      (key-binding "\C-i"))))
    ;; This is to satisfy `python-indent-line' which checks
    ;; `this-command' to cycle
    (setq this-command 'indent-for-tab-command)
    ;; Make people think this was called with C-i.  This allows
    ;; `self-insert-command' to work
    (setq last-command-event 9)
    (call-interactively command)))
```

To explain it a little bit, I let bind `gvol-mode` to `nil` so that when I do the key lookup my minor mode won't be in play.  Thus it will find the binding for <kbd><tab></kbd> or <kbd>C-i</kbd> that would be in place if the minor mode weren't on.  Then, in order for some functions to work I have to set `this-command` to `indent-for-tab-command`.  I also make it appear as if I typed <kbd>C-i</kbd> which allows it to work with `yasnippet-mode` IIRC.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you! It's especially nice to have those edge-case fixes, I'm sure you saved me a lot of frustration.

Comment: I was also successful using this method for [return] and C-m. Very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, there was a lot of frustration involved. `:-)`